# Limit of $\frac{3^{3n+3}+n^39^{9/n}}{9^n+n^93^{3/n}}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The problem I've is that I'm not sure which term dominates. If I divide by $3^{3n+3}n^9$:

$\lim \displaystyle \frac{3^{3n+3}+n^39^{9/n}}{9^n+n^93^{3/n}} = \lim\frac{3^{3n+3}+n^3 3^{18/n}}{3^{2n}+n^93^{3/n}}=\lim\dfrac{1/n^9+1/n^69^{18/n-3n-3}}{3^{-n-3}+{3}^{3/n-3n-3}} = \frac{0+0}{0+0}$

Which is indeterminate/undefined. Could someone please explain the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of result is inconclusive. We have
$$ n^3 9^{9/n}, n^9 3^{3/n} \in o(3^n)
$$
so these values become negligible as $n \to \infty$. Therefore,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^{3n+3} + n^3 9^{9/n}}{9^n + n^9 3^{3/n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^{3n+3}}{3^{2n}} = \infty
$$